# IIf And statement with multiple conditions

Tags: ms-access, multiple-conditions, iif

I'm very new to Access.
I'd like to make a column which has two conditions to result in "1" or "0".

The two conditions are:

> If the session ID is smaller than 154 AND their level average is
> bigger than the current level, "1" is assigned, otherwise, "0".

AND

> If the session ID is equal to or bigger than 154 AND the exam average
> is more than 2, "1" is assigned, otherwise, "0".

The syntax that I wrote is below, but it didn't work - returns 0 for every cell.

```vb
IIf([Session_ID]<154 And [Level_Avg]>[Current_Lvl],"1","0") And IIf([Session_ID]>=154 And [Exam_Avg]>=2,"1","0")
```

Could anyone take a look? Any comments are very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the quotes around the 1's and 0's.

Comment: Quotes around 1 and 0 is irrelevant to issue but certainly not needed. Edit question to show sample raw data and desired output as text tables. Your expression makes no sense.

Comment: Possibly should be `IIf(([Session_ID]<154 And [Level_Avg]>[Current_Lvl]) Or ([Session_ID]>=154 And [Exam_Avg]>=2), 1, 0)`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments here. I recognized that my expression made no sense with the conditions! I corrected the command as recommended and it worked. Also, extra thanks to edit my original post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need an OR operator between the two conditions as either one should return the 1 option, otherwise return 0.

```
IIf(([Session_ID]<154 And [Level_Avg]>[Current_Lvl]) Or ([Session_ID]>=154 And [Exam_Avg]>=2), 1, 0)
```